# how do i see data by using django listview at chrome

Tags: django, listview, templates

I used listview and confirmed that there was a query set in the terminal.
I want to see that data on the Internet. However, even though there is data, row of the table is not added.

[image]

What should I do?
It's so frustrating. I couldn't do anything for five hours because of this.
plz heeeeelp me...!

```
# html
{% extends 'branches/package-create.html' %}


{% block nav %}
<form method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for i in ps %}
    <tr class="content-tr">
        <td class="td1">{{ i.package_recommandation_date }}</td>
        <td class="td2">{{ i.package_payment_date }}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

```
# MODELS.PY
class PayHistory(models.Model):
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branch, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    package_recommandation_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    package_payment_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    ...
```

```
# views.py
class PackageListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'branches/package-get.html'
    model = PayHistory

    def get_queryset(self):
        p=PayHistory.objects.all()
        print(p)
        return p
```

```
# TERMINAL
<QuerySet [<PayHistory: PayHistory object (1)>, <PayHistory: PayHistory object (2)>]>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ListView` passes the data by default to the template as `object_list`, not `ps`, so you should set the [**`context_object_name`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.context_object_name) to:

```
class PackageListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'branches/package-get.html'
    model = PayHistory
    context_object_name = 'ps'
```

Comment: sooooooooo thx!!!!! It's all thanks to you.